# How to increase size of graph Javaplot

Tags: java, gnuplot, javaplot

I'm new to Javaplot and I'm using it to generate several graphs of some processes to determine their efficiency.

I've made my way around to be able to create several graphs in a page but they are very hard to read.

I know how to decrease the size of the labels but I wanted to know if there is a way to also decrease the size of the values of in the Axis because as you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjdl4.png), they are the problem, along with the text from the datasets.

The way I create the graps is basically:

```
Javaplot jp = new Javaplot();
Dataset ds;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
ds = new Dataset();
//fill dataSet
jp.setTitle("Title" + i); //Documentation says this method changes title of the graph
}
jp.plot();
```

Also, when I use jp.setTitle("graph" + i) to the graphs, they use all the same title (the last one that was set). I hope someone knows how to fix this too or I'll make another question to solve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Also, when I use jp.setTitle("graph" + i) to the graphs, they use all the same title (the last one that was set)* You are changing title of the same graph so what did you expect? You probably wanted to change series name not chart title

Comment: I thought that if I did jp.newGraph() and then jp.setTitle(..) I was changing the title of the "active" graph. If not, I couldn't find a "setTitle" method for the Graph class